# Thematic/Semantic tagging of associations in UML

Tags: uml

Is it possible to use semantic tags in UML associations (among classes) to express the wider semantic nature of the relationship?

For example, consider the relation that Doctor `TREATS` Patient. Beyond the TREATS relation, we also want to express that it's a `medical` and `humanitarian` relation. Is it possible to somehow tag the association between Doctor and Patient with these two additional tags in UML?

Also, consider the example of a Doctor's relation with another Doctor. We want a model where a Doctor can have multiple (semantic) relations such as `Professional`, `Social`and many other relations with another Doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "*tag*" UML element, you should take a look at the UML Stereotype concept.
In short it is a way to add domain related information to UML element.

In the following screenshot, I defined two stereotypes respectively named "humanitarian" and "medical" and I stereotyped a UML association with both of them.

[image]

Another solution would be to define a stereotype which has two boolean properties "humanitarian" and "medical" and set their values as true when the stereotyped is applied.

[image]

Comment: There is a third solution with uml "keywords", that are similar to stereotypes, but much simpler, since you don't have to design&deploy any profile before being able to use it.

Comment: The list of UML "keywords" is predefined in the specification. This list can not be enriched or extended and it is mostly related to UML metaclasses e.g. interface. So it will be be possible to add "medical" or "humanitarian" ..